# Lag occurs after loading from other scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

#### Assumptions / What I want to achieve

I am making an action game that moves only the x and z axes in 3D.
I'm trying to make this compatible with online multiplayer.The Player object has such a component.

[image: Player]

Use Joystick of StandardAssets for OnlinePlayerController.cs,
There is code to move using the rigidbody velocity.
The code is written below.

#### The problem I am having

Lag always occurs when loading an online scene from another scene.

#### Applicable source code

```
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class OnlinePlayerController : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public float speed;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject Rotation; //Omitted because it has nothing to do with movement

    void Update()
    {
        x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        z = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        rigd.velocity = new Vector3(x * speed, 0, z * speed);
    }
}
```

#### What I tried

As you can see from [this article](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/lagcompensation), I tried to fix the lag, but there was no change.

The Player object has a Rigidbody only to use **Rigidbody.velocity**.
Gravity is ineffective and friction with the floor is high and will not slip.

#### Supplementary information

Unity2019.2.6f1

PUN2 Free

---

It's important to note that there is no lag when playing from the scene in the editor.
I think that Photon is not the cause, as in other questions, but I think Unity is the major cause. (For example, the previous scene is interfering, etc.)

This is my first time using PUN2, so I don't know much about this.

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: From what youve showed us there is no other scene, you've not shown how you're loading it, what you're doing, when you're doing it...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, everything was my mistake.
This code was running before the scene transition.

**Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.2f;**